# Modifying objects list fileds saved as LONGBLOB in MySQL

Tags: mysql, jpa, arraylist, alter

I have a table "Project" in my MySQL Databse that contains an ArrayList saved as LONGBLOB (FiledDetailsData).

```
public class ProjectEntity implements Serializable {

 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
 private String projectName;
 private String city;
 private int nbFields;
 private List<FiledDetailsData> FiledDetails;...
```

I already have alot of data saved and would like to keep it. The problem is that I had to change to structure of FiledDetailsData to add new fields

I've changed it from

```
@Embeddable
@XmlRootEllement
public class FiledDetailsData implements Serializable`{

private String id;
private String lot;
private String number;
private String street;
private String size;
private String status;
```

to

```
@Embeddable
@XmlRootEllement
public class FiledDetailsData implements Serializable`{

private String id;
private String lot;
private String number;
private String street;
private String size;
private String status;
private BigDecimal extraField;
private BigDecimal extraParking;
```

When I try to run the application with the previous data, I get this error

```
Could not deserialize object from byte array. Internal Exception: local class incompatible
```

I can fin it by deleting the LONGBLOB in my DAtaBase and recreating it, but then I lose all my data.

here are my save/edit methods

```
 protected abstract EntityManager getEntityManager();

public void create(T entity) {
    getEntityManager().persist(entity);
}

public void edit(T entity) {
    getEntityManager().merge(entity);
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: if you had stored the List field in a join table then there would be no need to lose data, and you'd be able to query the embedded data...

Comment: Yes, unfortunately, I'm picking up some one else`s project and the tables already have their structure and alot of data

Comment: so run the app (with old definition of embedded type) and extract the List and store elsewhere in a join table, then do a database migration so that it uses a join table. That is the only clean way I see of retaining your data.